# Subtract two dates and times, and find if the later value exceeds 2 hours

Tags: date, time, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Writing a Google sheet, and need the formula to evaluate two dates and times, and determine if the later value exceeds 2 hours and a day.

IE,

```
In - Out
1/1/19 2:00 - 1/1/19 3:59
1/1/19 2:00 - 1/1/19 4:00
1/1/19 2:00 - 1/1/19 4:01
1/1/19 2:00 - 1/2/19 3:59
1/1/19 2:00 - 1/2/19 4:00
1/1/19 2:00 - 1/2/19 4:01
```

Heres my formula I use now

```
=IFERROR(
  ARRAYFORMULA(
  IF(ISBLANK($S3:$S),,
    FLOOR(
     IF(VALUE(TIME(HOUR($S3:$S),MINUTE($S3:$S),1)-TIME(HOUR($R3:$R),MINUTE($R3:$R),0))*24>2.01,
      ($S3:$S-$R3:$R)+1,
      ($S3:$S-$R3:$R)+1),1)
    )))
```

Where 'R' is In, and 'S' is Out.
Currently, I can't get it to exclude the first days' 2hr limit being exceeded while trying to get it to work on the everyother day perfectly fine.

So in the top example Ideally every line should come back as a '1' for 1 day other than the last one, 1/2/19 4:01. 
The scenario I am running by is that a person can rent something for a day, and have an overflow of 2 hours without getting marked as an additional day for being late.
Currently, it will count the last 4 rows of examples as 2 days.

I was trying to format the formula to include Date(Year(),Month(),Day(). However, I just ran into so many parsing errors, and couldn't figure a way past this.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IFERROR(
  ARRAYFORMULA(
    IF(ISBLANK(T3:T),,
        FLOOR(     
            IF(DATEVALUE($Q2:Q)+TIMEVALUE($R2:R)-DATEVALUE($N2:N)+TIMEVALUE($O2:O)>1,
                IF(R2:R-O2:O>0.08263888889,(T2:T-S2:S)+2,(T2:T-S2:S)+1),
                (T2:T-S2:S)+1)
        ,1
            )
        )
    )
```

This seems to be the best way I can get this to work.
I had to nest an IF statement so I can cut out the first day issue.
That strange 0.08 is the elapsed difference from 2 hours supposedly.

I Genuinely dont understand the Answer that I was given from Player0.
My situation has 3 different sticking points.
First day cannot add +2 if its over 2 hour difference.
Every other day can.
His strange number was 31.08, so maybe his is scaled for months or something.
I couldn't get it to work though, it would only return a '1'. When I broke down the Quotient and fiddled with it every answer was 0 for the most part. 
If Theres something im missing from this new formula. I would love to get some input.

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(S2:S), 
 IF((DATEVALUE(S2:S)+TIMEVALUE(S2:S))-
    (DATEVALUE(R2:R)+TIMEVALUE(R2:R))<=31.0833333333285, 1, 
 QUOTIENT((DATEVALUE(S2:S)+TIMEVALUE(S2:S))-
          (DATEVALUE(R2:R)+TIMEVALUE(R2:R))-31.0833333333285, 28)+2), ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: I had a problem where I had to format my in/out times for military time.
Then after resolving that, it wouldnt do anything but '1'.

Comment: well, do your military time in internal cell formatting as custom time and date

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/kqfxPMc.png
I wish I could say anything more. Ive never used 'Len' or Quotient before, so the syntax is beyond me. Im reading their documentation rn.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/3IeEWcF.png
The last image didnt even have something that would exceed the '1' day.
But my whole sheet went 1, so I knew something was up, lol myb.